# How to refresh data value loaded from external database in wordpress pages

Tags: php, ajax, database, wordpress, refresh

I want to display data values from an external mysql database in wordpress pages. 
I have used this php code which works fine inside a php widget :

```php
<?php

$host = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xx";
$user = "user";
$pass = "Password2000!";
$db_name = "my_database";

//create connection
$dbcon = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db_name);

//test if connection failed
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die("connection failed: "
        . mysqli_connect_error()
        . " (" . mysqli_connect_errno()
        . ")");
}
$sqlget = " SELECT Value FROM Points WHERE Name_ID = 'Hall' ";
$sqldata = mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlget);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqldata)) {
    echo sprintf('%.1f', $row['Value']);
    echo " °C";
}
}

?>
```

But my question is how to refresh the value periodically without reloading the page.
Best regards.

Comment: You'll need to add javascript and use a timer function to reload the content via AJAX.

Comment: For that you need to used ajax for reload data without page refresh.

Comment: Hello,thank you for your reply. Please how can i modify the php code to do this?